# Hyper-V Reverse Replication

Tags: hyper-v, replication

I have a master hyper-v replicated on a secondary server.

If the master fails and the secondary takes over, how do you replicate From the secondary to the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your master is failed the replication is over and interrupted. So you can switch the replication and so your secondary becomes the master and the master becomes the secundary.
To switch the replication you can do that directly in the hyperv interface.

Comment: Yeah , i just tested it. I wasnt understanding the concept.